# WhatsApp isnt letting me open the chat

Tags: whatsapp, lumia-520

Over the past hour I've been trying to send messages through whatsapp. (I have a lumia 520.) But when i click on the name, the app hangs and the chat doesn't open. I've tried locking the screen and trying again, turning off my phone. Nothing worked. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried deleting chats or clearing the history?

Answer (score 1):

reinstall the app. And turn off the restrict background data usage in data sense settings.